# Button click to add string to List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I would like to have a button that when clicked will take the text of what's inside the text box and add it to a list of strings.  Then, I have another button that when clicked will output the count of the list into another text box.  I keep on getting a count of zero, no matter what I try.  Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        itemList.Add(txtItem.Text);
        txtItem.Text = "";
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtItemListCount.Text = itemList.Count.ToString();

    }
}
```

markup

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">


    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" ID="txtItemListCount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" 
        onclick="Button2_Click" />


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
```

to

```
string itemListKey = "itemListKey";
List<string> itemList
{
  get
  {
     if ( Session[itemListKey] == null )
        Session[itemListKey] = new List<string>();
     return (List<string>)Session[itemListKey];
  }
}
```

Comment: I banged my head against the wall far too long.  The price of being a noob, I guess.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

itemsList is created all over again with each Postback (each time the server is called).
Try storing the list in the ViewState or Session...

Comment: Could you also provide code examples on populating and reading ViewState or Session?

Comment: Oops i didnt see your comment. Check out Wiktor's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to PostBack's good sir!

Everytime something on your active server page needs to make a request to the server, a "PostBack" is called, refreshing parts of your page life cycle such as Page_load.

You'll need to use the Session variable or ViewState variable,Session for an application wide variable, often described as the the shopping cart functionality on many websites. The cart variables carry through out each page request until the session is expired. On the other hand, the ViewState is only alive for the life cycle of the current page.

This is where you need to make a decision on what type of container you will use, a Session variable, or a ViewState variable.

A quick fix to show you the understandings would be to;

If the Session variable does not exists make it.

```
if (Session["myList"] == null)
            Session["myList"] = new List<string>();
```

Cast it to a list of strings to add your items.

```
List<string> myList = (List<string>)Session["myList"];
        myList.Add(txtItem.Text);
```

Update the session variable

```
Session["myList"] = myList;




  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["myList"] == null)
            Session["myList"] = new List<string>(); // Check that it exists

        List<string> myList = (List<string>)Session["myList"]; // Cast and add to your list
        myList.Add(txtItem.Text);

        Session["myList"] = myList; // Update the list

        txtItem.Text = "";
    }
```

Adjust your button2_click to load your session variable

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["myList"] == null)
            Session["myList"] = new List<string>();

        List<string> myList = (List<string>)Session["myList"];

        txtItemListCount.Text = myList.Count.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Web.UI.Page` is recreated on each request. So the `itemList` is initialized to `new List<string>();` when the button2 is clicked. Then the result count is zero.

You need to store the value of `itemList` between the requests, in some more durable resource (e.g. session, viewState, database etc.).